# If $u(x)=\int_0^x \sin(x-w)w^2 \, dw$, what is $u'$?

Tags: calculus

> If $u(x)=\int_0^x \sin(x-w)w^2 \, dw$, what is $u'$?

How to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus here?

If $f(x)=\int_0^x p(t)\,dt$ where $p(t)$ is a polynomial, then $f'(x)=p(x)$. Is it true in this case that we can just replace $w$ with $x$?

Comment: Short answer, yes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes and not exactly.

You should use Leibniz's rules. Let me quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule):

> In calculus, Leibniz's rule for differentiation under the integral sign, named after Gottfried Leibniz, states that for an integral of the form:
>    $$\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$
>    then for $-\infty < a(x), b(x) < \infty$ the derivative of this integral is expressible as
>   $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left (\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t \right )= f\big(x,b(x)\big)\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} b(x) \,-\, f\big(x,a(x)\big)\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} a(x) \,+\, \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{ \partial }{ \partial x} f(x,t) \,\mathrm{d}t$$

So you your case, you have $a(x) = 0, b(x)=x$ and $f(x,t)=\sin(x−t)t^2$, which gives you:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left (\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t \right )= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left (\int_{0}^{x} \sin(x−t)t^2\,\mathrm{d}t \right )= \\=\sin(x−x)x^2 \cdot 1 \,-\, f\big(x,a(x)\big)\cdot 0 \,+\,\left (\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sin(x−t)t^2\,\mathrm{d}t \right )$$

And so you get only one non-zero term:
$$\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sin(x−t)t^2\,\mathrm{d}t $$

So in this specific case you get the same answer that you were thinking about.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $u\left(x\right)=∫_0^x\sin \left(x-w\right)w^2dw=∫_0^x(\sin \left(x\right)\cos \left(w\right)w^2-\sin \left(w\right)\cos \left(x\right)w^2dw$

$=\sin \left(x\right)∫_0^x\cos \left(w\right)w^2dw-\cos \left(x\right)∫_0^x\sin \left(w\right)w^2dw$. Use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the product formula.

Comment: But why we can't apply the fundamental theorem of calculus directly?

Comment: Because you have $sin(x-w)$ which depends of $x$. In $\int_0^xp(t)dt$ $p$ does not depend of $x$.

Comment: That makes sense. And I think $\sin(x-w)=\sin(x)\cos(w)-\sin(w)\cos(x)$.